# Error While Generating Excel Sheet

Tags: c#, excel

I written code for generating Excel in C#. In Each and every system it works fine except the server. I think problem in excel settings

Error Message: ﻿ "Microsoft excel cannot open or save any more documents because there is not enough available memory or disk space,
Error Message: Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {00024500-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following error: 80070005............
"

Disk space is fine, RAM is at 2GB used (8GB total on machine)

﻿What I've tried: ﻿

1. Running dcomcnfg and setting identity table as "interactive user"
2. “C:\Windows\SysWOW64 \config\systemprofile\desktop” folder must also exist and you need Full Control permissions to the “systemprofile” and “desktop”
3. Properties > General > Unblock on file in file explorer

   ```
           - Right Click -> Properties of Excel File -> Client on Unblock
   ```

Can some one give the solution?
thanks.

Comment: Hi.. I believe there is an issue configuring Excel DCOM from a 64 bit machine. Run MMC /32 from the command line to force the 32 bit version to load and then configure the identity etc....